# Drag and Drop not working in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

[image]I need to drag and drop on web Element to another div on the same page. I tried using the following methods but none of the solutions are working. I can't go by coordinates either as there are multiple elements present in source class, and respective elements will be drag and dropped based on user inputs. I am fetching the latest chrome driver on the fly to run my browser.

**Browser**: Chrome (Version 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit))

**Solution1 attempted:**

```
WebElement from = driver. findElement(By.xpath(“”));
WebElement to = driver. findElement(By.xpath(“”));
act.dragAndDrop(from, to).perform();
```

**Solution2 attempted:**

```
WebElement from = driver. findElement(By.xpath(“”));
WebElement to = driver. findElement(By.xpath(“”));    
act.clickAndHold(from).build().perform();
act.moveToElement(to).build().perform();
act.moveByOffset(-1, -1).build().perform();
act.release().build().perform();
```

Comment: Is the drop location above or below the starting position?

Comment: it's to the left of starting position.I have added image. we move from Available configuration to select configuration

Comment: post the relevant html.